# Node.JS & nginx slow every 5-20 request

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a Node.Js, nginx setup on a ubuntu 16 server.

It all works, but sometimes when I request my service, the request takes op to 1 minute.

Can someone see if there is anything I'am doing wrong?

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL:!DH:!EDH:!AESGCM;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    server_name domain;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my-nat-ip:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_connect_timeout       300;
        proxy_send_timeout          300;
        proxy_read_timeout          300;
        send_timeout                300;
        proxy_buffers           32 4m;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size     25m;
        proxy_buffer_size 512k;
        proxy_ignore_headers "Cache-Control" "Expires";
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size        1024m;
        client_body_buffer_size     4m;
        proxy_intercept_errors off;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your Node code.

Unfortunately you didn't include it so it's impossible to tell you where.

Comment: "add a comment" ;)

Comment: Hi, I can see with DEBUG=express:* that my request does not take long on the node.js part. The problem is from my client to the node.js service, here is there sometimes a 5-8 seconds wait before the nodejs is being "hit", And I don't know why. When the node.js is handling the request its very fast.